# What does the symbol ! in SML mean?

Tags: sml, ml, ref

What does the symbol **!** in SML mean?

```
fun polysort(_,[]) = []
| polysort(_,[x]) = [x]!
| polysort(less,xs) =
 let
  val (ys, zs) = split xs
   in
   merge(less,polysort(less,ys), polysort(less, zs))
 end;
```

Does that reverse it or what? I think it has something to do with ref, but I don´t understand that either.

Comment: The prefix `!` operator appears to be the deference operator (get the value out of a `ref`), but I don't know about the postfix `!`. (Just from a quick google search)

Answer (score 9):

Normally, `!` is a function `'a ref -> 'a`, which [extracts the value from a reference cell](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/general.html#SIG%3aGENERAL.!%3aVAL). I.e.:

```
val x  = ref 1;  (* create reference cell *)
val () = x := 2; (* update value in x *)
val y = ! x;      (* extract value from x *)
```

However, in this case it looks like it's simply a typo.